# zsh: command not found: django-admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I installed django but when i run command **django-admin startproject send_email** it gives an error showing **zsh: command not found: django-admin** what can i do please help me. i search same question in google but the answers are not working

```
pathparakh@Paths-MacBook-Air send_email % django-admin startproject send_email
zsh: command not found: django-admin
pathparakh@Paths-MacBook-Air send_email % python3
Python 3.9.6 (v3.9.6:db3ff76da1, Jun 28 2021, 11:49:53) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(3, 2, 5, 'final', 0)
>>>
```

Comment: I think you have installed django globally, if so you need to find where its installed and then try startproject . Usually globally installed apps may be located at these kinds of locations - ```myHome/.local/bin/django-admin```. So use the full path like ```myHome/.local/bin/django-admin startproject mysite```. But the best way is to create virtual env and then create django project in it

Comment: zsh: no such file or directory: myHome/.local/bin/django-admin

Comment: Its just an example, check where is the django installed ? Else create a virtual env and then install django inside that !

Comment: how to check where is django installed in mac

Comment: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py' here is my django installed what command should i run

Comment: ```python -m django startproject mysite``` try this instead ?